# Hibernate @email validation failed

Tags: javascript, email, gwt, hibernate-validator

I have a problem with GWT client-side validation using hibernate validation annotation @Email. I put this annotation on entity getter and when I check constrains violations (agfter I put this email: test@test), than I get an error message "not a well-formed email address". But when I test this on server-side, than this email address pass. Have anyone of you this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EmailValidator` implementation provided by Hibernate Validator uses `java.util.regex.Pattern` to validate input strings. Since GWT cross-compiles Java code to Javascript, it only supports JS-level `RegEx` and as such does not allow `java.util.regex.Pattern` to be used.

As such, if you see the GWT re-implementation of `EmailValidator`, you'll see that this validator in particular is not implemented/supported: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/EmailValidator.java?av=h

Answer (score 9):

As workaround use the Pattern annotation:

```
@Pattern(regexp ="^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$")
```

Comment: This works. But the UI message is not user friendly. I found it better to rewrite the hibernate validator with a gwt version that uses RegEx instead of java.util.regex.Pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following mail:

```
test@test.test
```

And tell me the result.